# Does makefile treat .asm and .s as equal?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile system which has assembly files in it (.asm). Can I treat it equivalent to .s or do I need to explicitly specify to look for either .asm or .s?

Comment: Are you looking for implicit rules? Which make variant are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.asm` or `.s` should work just fine, for example.

```
file.o: assembly.s
```

or

```
file.o: assembly.asm
```

The only thing required is that the assembly syntax is constructed for the abi you're building for. Generally it seems `.s` is the more prevalent extension across platforms.